# Jquery loop with name increament

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm new to jquery and this easytask overwhelm me. I'd like to know how would you convert following code to one loop? Could anyone help?

```
$('#image1').change(function() {  
$('#input-image1 .error').hide();
});
$('#image2').change(function() {  
$('#input-image2 .error').hide();
});
```

Comment: You are hiding dom elements when the `change` event happens. What **exactly** would you need a loop for?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by 'one loop' you mean one event handling function, you can use a combination of classes to group the elements to select, and also `data-*` attributes to denote which element to target. Try this:

```
<input type="text" id="image1" data-target="input-image1" class="image" />
<input type="text" id="image2" data-target="input-image2" class="image" />

<div id="input-image1">
    <span class="error">error</span>
</div>
<div id="input-image2">
    <span class="error">error</span>
</div>
```

```js
$('.image').change(function() {  
     $('#' + $(this).data('target') + ' .error').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use a loop :

```
var i;
for (i=1; i<3; i++) {
    $('#image'+i).change(function() {  
        $('#input-image1'+i+' .error').hide();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery `$.each` to loop through your elements:

```
$.each($('#image1, #image2'), function (k) {
    $(this).on('change', function() {
        $('#input-image' + ++k + '.error').hide();
    });
});
```